# Storing for-loop output in one variable

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping

When I run my code, I get the price of the hotel I have defined in the url and after that I get the prices of all the other hotels that come as a suggestion. In order to subset and pick the first output, I need to store the for-loop output in a single variable or as a list. How do I do that?

I am using python 3.6.5, windows 7 professional

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
chrome_path= r"C:\Users\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
  dr = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
  dr.get("url")
 hoteltrial = dr.find_elements_by_class_name("hotel-info")

for hoteltrial1 in hoteltrial:
  nametrial = hoteltrial1.find_element_by_class_name("hotel-name")
  print(nametrial.text + " - ")
try:
    pricetrial = hoteltrial1.find_element_by_class_name("c-price")
    price = pricetrial.find_element_by_css_selector("span.price-num")
    currency = pricetrial.find_element_by_class_name("price-currency")
    print(currency.text + price.text)

except NoSuchElementException:
    print("sold")
```

The actual output looks somewhat like this and I need the price of only Langham

```
The Langham Hong Kong - 
$272
Cordis Hong Kong - 
$206
Island Shangri-La - 
$881
```

Comment: Do you still want to print the rest or you just want the 1st value?

Comment: just the first value.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is overriding the variables you use in your for-loop. For every iteration, the new value found is assigned to the variable in the loop.

```
for i in range(5):
    x = i
```

When you run this example and look at the value assigned to x after the for-loop, you'll see that the value is 4. You are doing the same in your code.

To solve this you can define a list outside of the for-loop and append the results to this list.

```
hotel = []
for i in range(5):
    hotel.append(i)
```

After running the above code you will see that this results in a list.

```
hotel
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

You should do the same in you code.

```
hotellist = []
for hoteltrial1 in hoteltrial:
    nametrial = hoteltrial1.find_element_by_class_name("hotel-name")
    hName = nametrial.text + " - "
    try:
        pricetrial = hoteltrial1.find_element_by_class_name("c-price")
        price = pricetrial.find_element_by_css_selector("span.price-num")
        currency = pricetrial.find_element_by_class_name("price-currency")
        result = hName + currency.text + price.text
        hotellist.append(result)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        result = hName + "Sold"
        hotellist.append(result)
```

After running this for-loop you will have a list with all the results found in each iteration of the loop. You could use a dictionary instead, so you could get each hotel and price by searching for the key.

Use dict:

```
hoteldict = {}
for hoteltrial1 in hoteltrial:
    nametrial = hoteltrial1.find_element_by_class_name("hotel-name")
    try:
        pricetrial = hoteltrial1.find_element_by_class_name("c-price")
        price = pricetrial.find_element_by_css_selector("span.price-num")
        currency = pricetrial.find_element_by_class_name("price-currency")
        hoteldict.update({nametrial.text:currency.text+price.text})
    except NoSuchElementException:
        hoteldict.update({nametrial.text:"Sold"})
```

For dictionary use update instead of append.

Access your hoteldict:

```
hoteldict["The Langham Hong Kong"] #Will return $272
```

I hope this helped you.
Kind regards,
Sam